# bootstrap 4 change color of nav-pill active

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I can assign custom background color for each of the pills, but what I really would like is to have a faded color of each custom one (which is just a matter of changing the values in the above), and have the active color match that full color of corresponding pill.

- pill one > faded red
- pill two > faded blu
- pill three > faded black

When

- pill one active > red
- pill two active > blu
- pill three active > black

my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item pill-1">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">pill one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item pill-2">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">pill two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item pill-3">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">pill three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.pill-1 a {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

bootstrap override

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @phiter sorry for not being clear, yes, unfortunatelly I can't think other ways to word it, custom active color for each pill.

Comment: @ZimSystem I did try some casual combination hoping to get lucky, since I am not good at it. I added what I did to override bootstrap active code to change the color, and don't have anything else, except the pill-2 and pill-3 which are same as pill-1 except for the color value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the appropriate CSS specificity for the active/inactive pills. For example:

https://www.codeply.com/go/Oe6EteovP0

```
/* not active */
.nav-pills .pill-1 .nav-link:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.nav-pills .pill-2 .nav-link:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 250, 0, 0.5);
}

.nav-pills .pill-3 .nav-link:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5);
    color: white;
}


/* active (faded) */
.nav-pills .pill-1 .nav-link {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: white;
}

.nav-pills .pill-2 .nav-link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 250, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-pills .pill-3 .nav-link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.2);
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Should have downvoted you, I had said non-active faded ;) (kidding of course)

Comment: Thanks, helpfull!